# Regex match and replace in C#

Tags: c#, regex, replace

I have string like

```
[any characters]{$\prime$}[any characters]$[any characters]{$\prime$}[any characters]$[any characters]
```

I want to replace the `$\prime$` that is inside $ "The second one" to be replaced by \prime
so the output from replace is

```
[any characters]{$\prime$}[any characters]$[any characters]{\prime}[any characters]$[any characters]
```

How can I do that using Reqex.Replace

and here is the code I use

```
trannsformContent = Regex.Replace(trannsformContent, @"(\$)(?<cont>.*?)(\$)\\prime(\$)(?<cont1>.*?)(\$)", @"${cont}\prime{cont1}$", RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.Singleline | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

Comment: Are those `$` and `*` chars literal? Or pseudo regex? Better add 1+ concrete input/output samples.

Comment: Can you show the code you are trying that doesn't work?  What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution :

```
trannsformContent = Regex.Replace(trannsformContent, @"\${1}(?<cont>.*?)\${1}\\prime\${1}(?<cont1>.*?)\${1}", @"$$${cont}\prime${cont1}$", RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.Singleline | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```